# Font-family usage in android

Tags: android, android-fonts

- To use fonts in android now , we directly use `android:fontFamily="@font/yourFont"` in android and we can apply the font on a view directly.
- If we have different versions of same font such as **bold,italic,normal** we can create a font-family as::

***font/lobster.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/lobster_regular" />

    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/lobster_italic" />

    <font
        android:fontStyle="bold"
        android:fontWeight="600"
        android:font="@font/lobster_bold" />
</font-family>
```

- Now my question is that how can I directly use the italic version of font,
  not directly with `android:fontFamily="@font/lobster_italic"` but with `lobster.xml` reference.

Comment: Thanks RobCo .The system can select the correct font based on the text style you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml use

```
android:fontFamiliy="@font/lobster"
android:textStyle="italic"
```

Or in code

```
textview.setTypeface(textview.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);
```

Comment: Setting android:textStyle="italic" will use font/lobster_italic ?.

Comment: Yes, if the system can find an appropriate italic font to use, which should be the case here.